# How we can get App become active in Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
NotificationCenter.default
            .publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)
            .sink { [self] _ in
                print("App become active")
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
```

In iOS Swift we can check that app becomes active by using this code in a specific class, but how we can do it in Android Kotlin

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "active"?

Comment: It is not possible on android, I figured it out